# How can I determine if a bridge site is legit?

Tags: bridge

I have seen online tutorials recommend Hop and Polygon bridges for transferring ETH from Polygon network to mainnet. Recently I came across the relatively new Umbria Narni bridge which claims much lower fees than other bridges. Is there a way I can verify if this is legit? Is there a guarantee based on Ethereum's smart contracts or history of previous transactions I can view?

Answer (score -1):

1. Check a DeFi data aggregator like L2beat.com to see the volume the
   bridge is processing to gauge its popularity (liquidity).
2. View the bridge's smart contract activity by pasting the bridge's 0x address into Etherscan.
3. Also ask the protocol for its external audits.